# Watch a single variable on Angular

Tags: angular

So, I searched and none of the posts helped me. I want to watch for a single variable change that is not an @Input(), ngOnChanges only watch for @Input() variables. I Want this:

```
date: Date;

ngInit() {
 this.date.watch(() => {
  dateChanged();
 }) 
}

dateChanged() {
  //do something
}
```

In React I used to use useEffect to do this and it was very practical, I want something like useEffect.

```
date: Date;

useEffect(() => {
  //do something
}, [date])
```

Component.ts

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

  //want to watch for initialDate changes
  initialDate: Date;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
```

Component.html

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="initialDate" dateFormat="dd.mm.yy" class="p-mr-2" icon="pi pi-calendar" showIcon="true"></p-calendar>
```

I could use onSelect event, but I want to know if it's possible to watch for changes on a single variable.

Comment: Maybe just use a setter?

Comment: Subject, BehaviorSubject

Comment: If this is a variable and not an input how is it changing? Can you show your code? It seems like you would have to be changing the variable's value in code so why not just add a method in the code to do whatever you are wanting to do when you  change the value in code?

Comment: I'm using [(ngModel)]="initialDate" on a primeng date picker, and it changes the variable initialDate: date;

Comment: You can monitor [(ngModel)] by pulling it apart. Something like <input [ngModel]="bar" (ngModelChange)="modelChangeFn($event)">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `(ngModelChange)="onDateChange()"` where you changing your date then in your .ts

```
onDateChange(){
//do your operation
}
```